# вывод псевдографики в консоль

Tags: c++, visual-studio, кодировка

Хочу вывести псевдографику в консоль:

```
std::cout << "┌───────────┐" << std::endl;
```

данные символы в консоль выводятся если выводить их по коду, но если указать символы прямо в коде, то выходит:

> warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name
> '\u250C' cannot be represented in the current code page (1251)

указанную выше строку я собрал копируя символы, которые выводились в консоли

подскажите, можно ли как-то исправить данную проблемы не переходя в юникод и не выводя код через коды?

Comment: Ваш файл исходника сохранен в кодировке 1251, а консоль в 866. Для начала я бы перевел сорцы в эту кодировку, тогда можно  будет открыть таблицу 866 и подсмотреть там нужные коды и вводить через alt+... Но я бы так не делал.

Comment: @KoVadim, а чтобы порекомендовали? чтобы наглядно в исходнике можно было бы использовать такие вещи? перевести консоль в 1251 и использовать уже соответствующие символы?

Comment: cp1251 не содержит этих символов. используйте юникод.

Comment: *" можно ли как-то исправить данную проблемы не переходя в юникод и не выводя код через коды"* - нет, это же символы юникода

Comment: т.е. перевести исходник в юникод, сделать юникодный вывод и не париться?

Comment: да. либо использовать ncurse. Либо скачать сорцы Far и посмотреть, как они сделали